# compare fast two memory regions

Tags: c++, c

How to compare fast two (variable size) memory regions as binary?

```
int compare (void *a,void *b,size_t size){
...
}


// reg1 > reg2
reg1 = 00001000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (binary);
reg2 = 00000100000000000000000000000000000000000000 (binary); 

if (compare(reg1,reg2,32) > 0){
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
};
```

Comment: [`std::memcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy)?

Comment: Did profiling show you this is where the performance bottleneck is?

Comment: memcmp compare direction left-right?

Answer (score 3):

All comparisons are performed using native binary because that is the internal representation, unless you need to compare the textual representation of a binary number.

For a platform specific answer, check the assembly language for your platform's processor.  Many modern processors have assembly language instructions for comparing regions of memory.

As other commenters have stated, `memcmp` is your best choice because it should be optimized for your platform.

If you must write your own, I suggest loading a word from memory and comparing memory word by word until there is not a match.  If you need more details, compare the words byte by byte to find where the exact difference is.