# A shortcut to compare data on the heap in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, comparison, heap-memory

Consider two arrays of data allocated on the heap:

```
int *A = new int[5];
int *B = new int[5];

// Some code which changes data pointed to by A and B
```

Now I want to compare these two arrays (not the pointers, but the data A and B point at). That is, I want to check out if the elements of the arrays are equal.

One might suggest elementwise comparison with a loop, but since there are functions such as `memcpy` which allow to avoid looping through data to copy it, it seems reasonable to assume there is a similar function which would allow to avoid looping through an array for elementwise comparison.

Does `C++` have any shortcuts for this?

Comment: What is length of array in real code?

Comment: `memcpy` doesn't avoid looping through an array. It is implemented with a loop. Generally speaking, if you need to compare array elements, there's a loop somewhere.And it doesn't matter whether the data is on the heap or in the stack. Arrays are arrays.

Comment: @PeteBecker I actually do not care how it is implemented. I just do not want to write a loop each time I have to deal with basic operations on arrays. If there are loops inside a built-in routine, let them be, at least I do not have to reinvent a wheel each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're mentioning `memcpy`, there's also [`memcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp).
This seems to be what you're after?

See also [Compare fast two memory regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880067/compare-fast-two-memory-regions).